# how to declare the type in my functional component?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I wanted to declare the type in my component this way, I already saw that this is possible using classes, but how could I do it using functional components? Without having to export the interface? I have already researched a lot and found nothing about it.

```js
const Elem1 = forwardRef((props : any, ref : { open()? : void }) => {
   useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
       open: () => console.log('opened')
   }))

   ....
})

const Elem2 = () => {
    const elem1Ref = useRef<Elem1>()

    elem1Ref?.current?.open()

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i got right, you should use the type parameters provided by the TS Generics definition of `forwardRef`. Like this

```js
const Elem1 = forwardRef<YourRefType, YourPropsType>((props, ref) => {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I already tried to use this syntax, but VS Code provides this error in useRef:

'Elem1' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Elem1'?

Answer (score 0):

I've been researching and from what they said, it is not possible to declare the type of a functional component, just by exporting the component's separate interface, thanks anyway!